# Doctrine DBAL Visitor pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns, doctrine-orm

DBAL in Doctrine has implementation of Visitor pattern.
There are an interface with a few accept-methods.

```
interface Visitor
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function acceptSchema(Schema $schema);

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function acceptTable(Table $table);

    public function acceptForeignKey(Table $localTable, ForeignKeyConstraint $fkConstraint)
    {
    }
}
```

And some classes like

```
class Schema
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function visit(Visitor $visitor)
    {
        $visitor->acceptSchema($this);

        if ($visitor instanceof NamespaceVisitor) {
            foreach ($this->namespaces as $namespace) {
                $visitor->acceptNamespace($namespace);
            }
        }

        foreach ($this->_tables as $table) {
            $table->visit($visitor);
        }

        foreach ($this->_sequences as $sequence) {
            $sequence->visit($visitor);
        }
    } 
}
```

Why method `Schema::visit` has parameter named `$visitor` ?
All definitions of Visitor tells that exactly `Visitor` should have method `visit`.  So `accept` method should be inside of `Visitable`
So is there are some naming issues with `Schema::visit($visitor)`? Is `DBAL\Visitor` in fact `Visitable`? If this is true, why `Visitor::accept` does not call $schema->visit($this) ?

Some implementation of `Dbal\Visitor` looks like

```
  /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function acceptSequence(Sequence $sequence)
    {
        $this->sequences->attach($sequence);
    }
```

Is it not necessary to call `$visitor->visit($this)` inside of `Visitable::accept()`?